# How to display dynamic text boxes infront of each other

Tags: php, html, css

Please help me with the display of my webpage.

The image below shows three text boxes with their respective names above.
Please how can I use CSS to make them display infront of each other i.e on the same (single) line, and each header center aligned on it's box ?

Each box header is generated from the database (php/mysql), while the text box is added inside the loop that generates the header.

Image
[image]

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

this is the code I'm using to generate this display

```
 <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) ?>" method               ="post"> 
           <?php             
          while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){                       
       echo $row['senatorial']."</br>" ;?>
```

```
          <?php  } ;?>
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" />
                <input type='submit' name='submit' class='OpenInput_Btn' value='Create' title='Register Constituency' />
                </form> 
                <?php  
     }
```

?>

**CSS**

```
.consistuency{
             display: inline;
             margin-left: 90px;
             font-size: 15px;
             font-family: Calibri:
        } 


     label {
            width: 8em;
            float: left;
            display: block;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            color: Beige;
            }
```

Comment: Wow, can you rephrase the question?

Comment: For this you will need to provide us the HTML structure you are using. CSS is highly dependent on your markup afterall.

Comment: ...and the CSS you have right now as well.

Comment: You will have to modify your CSS where it says `position` as well as check for any line breaks e.g. `<p>` and/or `<br>` - `<br />`. Best I can say without seeing any actual `code`.

Comment: @fred I've updated the question with the php code I'm using to display.

Comment: Thanks but this alone will not control the placement of your form. There surely must be an accompanied `.css` file with what you're working with, or embedded in your HTML(?)

Comment: @Fred . I have update the code i used in generating the display and also the CSS i'm implementing. 
Thanks

Comment: Start by commenting out `float: left;` and/or `display: block;` with `/* css code */` and see what the results will be.

Comment: @fred I did as you said, but there's no change in the display.

Comment: The only thing left that I can tell, is the `<br />` in `echo $row['senatorial']."</br>" ;?>` Try using `echo $row['senatorial']."" ;?>`. After that I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep your labels as they are, wrap each label/field pair in a div, give those divs a class name (say, "fieldWrapper") and give that class `display: inline-block;`:

```
.fieldWrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: But did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Yes I did. It didn't have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the textboxes with their headers next to each other in a single line, so just as bfavaretto said, use divs.

Add div tags to this code in the while loop:

```
  <label for='name'></label>     
          <input type='text' name='constituency' class='OpenInput_Text' />
                 </br>
```

If you know exactly how many rows will be returned from the db table then you can set the div widths to a percentage, in this case something like %30.

Otherwise you can count the numbers of rows returned and use this value to calculate a percentage/width for the divs and then set it with inline css.